# Jenkins can't save global tool configuration

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 2.70, and the system is CentOS 7.064 bit. 
My Jenkins is installed in Yum mode However, after installation, there are some problems, such as in Global Tool Configuration, except for Maven Configuration, JDK, and git. the rest of the settings all can not be saved .
 Can you help me out?